# how to validate the json username and password and to display the particular info

Tags: ios, json

I have one login screen, where user want to login with the user id and password. When particular logged in - the particular user data alone should be display in two labels.

```
jsonObject = @[@{@"Id1":@"mad”,@“Password”:@“123”,
                     @“Earning”:@“300”,@“Extra”:”1000”,},
                   @{@"Id2":@"normal”,@“password”:”111”,
                     @“Earning”:@“9”,@“Extra”:@“300"}];
```

How can i validate that username and password to display the two "earning " and " extra" data alone in label in next screen.

Like below image:

[image]

Now how can i validate that username to allow user to see their particular data in that label in next view

Like wise when particular user logged in, their data alone should display.BUt while do for check username id and password. How can i validated using `if` statement.

Please explain me some code.

Comment: where is your set of user account stored ? what does JSON have to do with this ?

Comment: Actually that username and password is  that json id is username and password is password

Comment: Show us what you have done so far?

Comment: i used some data to display. But i am new to this. don't know how to validate the username and password and to show the particular logged user data alone

Comment: i need the if statement to validate the userid and password , and to show the particular data in label